# CPPUnit vs CPPUnit2

Tags: unit-testing, cppunit

I just noticed that CPPUnit2 exists.

Is anyone here using it?  Or is CPPUnit the more commonly used of the 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a fork which went nowhere, judging by the lack of committing. It started with some high-sounding goals.

The home page on sourceforge is confusingly blank, most of the action is on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/cppunit2).

I have used cppunit recently enough to add the VS2008 projects.

Comment: CppUnit2 does not seem to have changed much since May 2010 either (as of March 1, 2014).

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully constructed CppUnit for the recent C++Builder 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, and 32-bit OS X platform compilers, using the CppUnit contrib/bc5 files and the article [CppUnit Tests with C++BuilderX](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32704) by Charlie Calvert as guides.

I am in the process of determining how to add new readme files, the modified source and makefiles to the SourceForge [CppUnit - C++ port of JUnit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/) project.  I have also successfully built CppUnit for the clang and clang++ compilers, included in the Apple Xcode command line tools for OS X Mavericks, by following the instructions within the CppUnit INSTALL text file.  I then used [NetBeans 7.4](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/) to successfully integrate the clang and clang++ compilers into my project.

NetBeans 7.4 is CppUnit aware, so the test running results are shown inside NetBeans (see the [NetBeans IDE 7.4 Installation Instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/74/install.html)).  The NetBeans [FaqCplusPlusUnitTest](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCplusPlusUnitTest) has a little bit of detail, recommending the integrated IDE Help topics for more information.  See my [CppUnit compatibility for nucleus RTOS](https://sourceforge.net/p/cppunit/discussion/37107/thread/30198184/#b11f) response for additional details on how to set the CC and CXX variables for the CppUnit *configure* script execution.

There are additional references.  Two helpful ones are 1) [Unit testing for C++ code - Tools and methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology) with two recent posts of July 2013 and October 2013 and 2) [Exploring the C++ Unit Testing Framework Jungle](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle) by Noel, updated April 2010.  Within Noel's article is the statement that CppUnit is probably the most widely used C++ unit testing framework. A comparison of the lighter UnitTest++ to CppUnit downloads on SourceForge shows UnitTest++ with 113 this week and CppUnit with 899 downloads this week (probably ending March 1, 2014).