# Suggestion for UnitTest tools for C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++

I am startting to develop a module using C++ and yes using VC++ 6.0. Had a look on [google test framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) but it supports VC 7.1 onwards.

Can any body please suggest few tools for unittesting C++ exes or dlls. If the tool can be integrated to VC++ 6.0 IDE will be great.

Comment: Tried Nunit ? Works fine for me.

Comment: @DumbCoder: For C++? And not managed C++, if he’s using VC6.

Comment: @sbi,Can you suggest any other version please? considering that I have to mainly develop shellextensions (COM-ATL Projects) :)

Comment: No, I can't, because I have never done any COM/ATL stuff and don't know what it takes. But VC6 was awfully bad in parsing anything that mentioned the keyword `template` and gave us a lot of headaches back then. We happily put it away when VC7.1 (2003) came along.

Answer (score 3):

And I use [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/).

Also take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology).

Answer (score 1):

CppUnit

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Try Boost.Test (we use it with VS 2005 and I think it's great).

I'm not sure how well it'd work w/rgd to integration, but we use a simple post-build steps to execute the unit tests and that should work in VC6 as well.

While current boost releases no longer officially support MSVC-6, we here use boost 1.34.1 for regular expressions in VC6 and VC8. We do not *use* the *testing* framework in VC6, but I checked our build directory and we *do* build the testing framework for VC6 as well. (because we build regex for both VC6 and VC8, the script just builds test as well)

Since the Boost testing framework seems to mostly rely on macro magic (as opposed to template magic) you might actually stand a good chance even a current version of it is working in VC6.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [unit.hpp](https://github.com/burner/sweet.hpp/blob/master/unit.hpp). I wrote it because I couldn't find any testing framework that I liked. It is very small (371 loc c++11) any should do most task required for unit testing.