# Limitations of using a C unit testing framework for testing embedded C++ code

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, testing

I would like to try using a unit testing framework for testing the code that I write in C, C++ or sometimes IEC languages too.

So my question is - **is there some big limitation using C-written unit test Framework for testing C++ code** that would restrain me from using it?

---

*Background info:*
 *I tried a variety of frameworks available as opensource - that are written in C / C++. And finally I concluded that 'embedded unit' - written in C and 'CppTest' - written in C++ were the candidates (mainly because the testing has to be performed on an embedded platform). But before selecting the winner I fell into this very Basic question . And to my knowledge I find no big limitations. 
Except that: In C++ Unit testing framework:I can make the testClass a friend of testable class and test its private attributes/ functions (which is not really important for me). sorry if this is a silly question - i just started exploring the world of testing.*

Comment: [The code as in "program code" is used as mass noun. So it is "code", not "codes".](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context)

Comment: What's your problem using a unit testing framework written in C++ for testing C code? I'm doing this using gtest, and it works fine for me ...

Comment: See here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology#92569

Comment: If your concern is that you want to run your unit tests on a resource limited embedded target, you should make this clear in your question. But I have also brought gtest running on a (not so resource limited) embedded platform.

Comment: @g-makulik I didn't say I face problems using C++ written unit testing framework. Also I didn't face problem running cpptest / embeddedunit in my highly resource limited customised embedded platform. My question is exactly what I have mentioned above - with no offense :)

Comment: Are you compiling with C++?  If so, then it is C++ code?  I wouldn't anticipate any problems, as long as you are happy writing your tests in a 'C' like subset of C++.

Comment: BTW, I've used the following for embedded.  Its pure C and I use it for C code, so maybe not applicable to your situation, but I didn't see it in your list. https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity/

Answer (score 3):

One example is that you will be hard pushed to test expected C++ exceptions generated by your code under test using a strict C framework.  I am sure there are other holes in this approach, but it depends on your C++ code.

Unless you have a really good reason, CppTest seems like the logical choice of your two candidates.  I've linked in comments to a question that might cover options you have missed.

Comment: Thanks, I did try few options including (CppUnit,CxxTest,CppTest,Catch,Fructose,Cutest,Cute,testape,maestra,easyunit,cut,gtest,cpputest,yaffut). And CppTest and embedded unit were the candidates mainly because of the embedded platform (our own IDE, RTOS and Hardware(PLC)) limitations.

Comment: @SteveTownsend, as long as the 'C'-like unit test function is compiled in C++, then the OP should be able to try/catch within the unit test function?