# How to test Simple Cpp file?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I wrote a simple program in Cpp but I have no idea what is the best approach to test this? Is there a certain format for unit testing like in Java?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
static vector<int> getAllFlipLocations(
        vector<int> & pancakesRepresentedByDiameter);

/**
 * Problem statement can be viewed at:
 * http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=downloadproblem&probid=110402&format=html
 *
 * The following is a solution for the above problem.
 *
 * @author Quinn Liu (quinnliu@vt.edu)
 */
int main(void) {
    string stackOfPancakes;

    while (getline(cin, stackOfPancakes)) {
        istringstream is(stackOfPancakes);

        vector<int> pancakesRepresentedByDiameter;

        int diameterOfPancake;
        while (is >> diameterOfPancake) {
            pancakesRepresentedByDiameter.push_back(diameterOfPancake);
        }
        reverse(pancakesRepresentedByDiameter.begin(),
                pancakesRepresentedByDiameter.end());

        vector<int> orderOfFlipLocations = getAllFlipLocations(
                pancakesRepresentedByDiameter);

        // first print original stack of pancakes
        cout << stackOfPancakes << endl;

        // now print location within stack to flip pancakes to get a stack
        // of pancakes where the pancake diameters decrease as they move
        // from the bottom to the top
        for (int i = 0; i < orderOfFlipLocations.size(); i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
            cout << orderOfFlipLocations[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

/**
 * Return the order of the locations to flip pancakes in the pancake stack.
 */
vector<int> getAllFlipLocations(vector<int> &pancakesRepresentedByDiameter) {
    vector<int> orderOfFlipLocations;

    vector<int>::iterator beginIndex = pancakesRepresentedByDiameter.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator endIndex = pancakesRepresentedByDiameter.end();

    for (int i = 0; i < pancakesRepresentedByDiameter.size(); i++) {
        vector<int>::iterator currentIndex = beginIndex + i;
        vector<int>::iterator maximumIndex = max_element(currentIndex,
                endIndex);

        // iterate through the stack of pancakes
        if (currentIndex != maximumIndex) {

            if (maximumIndex + 1 != endIndex) {
                // adds value of (maximumIndex - beginIndex + 1) to the end of the vector
                orderOfFlipLocations.push_back(maximumIndex - beginIndex + 1);
                reverse(maximumIndex, endIndex);
            }
            orderOfFlipLocations.push_back(i + 1);
            reverse(currentIndex, endIndex);
        }
    }
    orderOfFlipLocations.push_back(0);
    return orderOfFlipLocations;
}
```

Comment: C++ has no built-in method for generating/running unit tests, but a quick google search will turn up quite a selection of unit testing frameworks.

Comment: I like to use gookletest/googlemock, but there are a number of other testing framworks to use for c++.

Answer (score 0):

No, out of the box C++ does not have any unit testing. Many IDEs do these days, though. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385.aspx) is method to unit test in Visual Studio, and there is also frameworks out of which few worth mentioning are [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/), [UnitTest++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unittest-cpp/) or [Google C++ Testing Framework](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/). If you are looking for something more specific, you can check out older thread on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology#92569).