# C++ unit testing with VS test professional

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

Does any one know if I can test native code in VS Test 2010?

Comment: You should ask at http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Ian C. I did and so far no one answered

Comment: Can you define native code more explicitly?  Are you talking about C++ code where you have the headers and the libraries, the source code, or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of VS2010, native C++ unit testing is not directly supported by Visual Studio.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243171.aspx), specifically:

> You cannot have test projects with unit tests that use unmanaged C++.

You can still do native C++ unit testing with Visual Studio, but it won't be as integrated as other VS features.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150/how-to-set-up-unit-testing-for-visual-studio-c/35963#35963) for a number of native unit testing frameworks and libraries.  I have not used any of those, so I cannot give any guidance there.

Answer (score 1):

I would bite the bullet, download Boost and get the test suite compiled.  Once you get into it, it's as easy as VS tests.

Comment: Or if you don't want to pull in boost (which is great BTW) go for UnitTest++.