# Need Visual Studio 2005 Compatible C++ Unit Testing Framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, frameworks, visual-studio-2005

Would you please recommend a C++ unit testing framework which works on Visual Studio 2005 and has all or most of features? I cant find any.
And please give a guide\tutorial to use it.

Comment: "all or most" of _what_ features?

Comment: Here is an older question with a lot of related, but still relevant links.  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150/how-to-set-up-unit-testing-for-visual-studio-c>  I've used cxxtest with it with some luck, but I've also heard good things about the google test framework.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) and [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/) on VS2005 without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

here I am using [Google C++ Testing Framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) which works well with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition. For a tutorial you can check the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Documentation)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005

Answer (score 0):

Visual Assert should be compatible with Visual Studio 2005.
I haven't tried it though.
http://www.visualassert.com/unit-testing-framework/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe any FW which supports latest version of Visual Studio will will do, as Visual Studio 2005 is quite similar to the those.

Anyway, both CxxTest and GTest worked for my.